# Dynamic Table name generation results in "Table Not found"

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pdi

Using Pentaho and Spoon. i have a combination of transforms that

1. Creates a new table name variable (TABLENAME)

In a separate transformation I'm attempting to use this table name

1. first step creates a list of column names (generate rows step)
2. second step uses these table rows and the table name from the previous transformation (Table output step)

When i click the SQL button on the Table Output Step, it returns the correct create table statement. (although it doesn't replace the placeholder, it does return a CREATE TABLE....)

when i attempt to run these two transformations in-line, it complains that the table with my generated name does not exist. It appears that instead it must be trying to INSERT into this generated table, when the sql button returns a CREATE.

how do i make pentaho create a table with a generated name stored in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Table Output step doesn't create the table, the SQL button is like a help button, it only allows you to copy the DML to create the table and paste it to wherever you want to run it, but that step doesn't run the create table order.

You'll need a separate transformation or job to create the table before inserting into it. For jobs there's an action to run SQL statements, one similar step for transformations.

Comment: Thank you. this helped! I find it annoying and frustrating that these types of DDL activities aren't built into the product, but i'll take it for what it is.

Comment: Well, they added the button as help, but Pentaho it's not specific to any database, so the DDL generated is pretty basic, each database has specific commands to fine tune the management of tables, creation of indexes, sequences, etc, so the DDL provided is just an starting point to a proper database management

Comment: Besides, it's not usual to create the table each time you run the transformation, the usual is create the table once during development, and then each time you run the transformation you add data to the table, or truncate the table before adding the information for this execution. There are scenaries where the creation of temporary tables each time you run a transformation is valid, but you'll need a separate logic to drop those tables once you don't need them, or maybe you want your datamodel created and documented in Pentaho, so this transformation is meant to run only once.